# can't find '__main__' module in cmd with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started coding in python3 and for a school project we had to write a .txt file with the matrix in it and a .py file in which i am supposed to import the .txt file and execute the code. Everything should be executed in cmd with the following syntax: python matrix_input.txt matrixReloaded.py.
But i execute the code in cmd i get the following error:  can't find '**main**' module.
The .txt file i a simple text file with just the matrix in it. 
In my .py file I had to create a directory for both the .txt file and the .py file and then follows the code that executes certain stuff on the matrix.
I tried multiple stuff but since I'm new to this nothing worked.
How do i fix this?

Comment: reorder your arguments: `python matrixReloaded.py matrix_input.txt `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a python script to execute it needs to have an entry point defined. That entry point is the `main` module. You are getting the error because it's not defined in your script. So, in your script, `matrixReloaded.py`, you want to include this module like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_something()
```

Now, in order to execute the script from shell, you need to specify the script, and only then the arguments that you are trying to pass (in your case, a name of a file): `python matrixReloaded.py matrix_input.txt`

Lastly, to access the arguments (and then open the file or whatever you need to do with it), you will need to include the `sys` module. Here's an example:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print sys.argv[0] # prints matrixReloaded.py
    print sys.argv[1] # prints matrix_input.txt
```